# How to use Tkinter Buttons to help in calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello programmers from around the world, welcome to a new day.

I have an project I made using Python, it is a calculator with GUI made using Tkinter, it's name is CalculatorX. You can check the code here on GitHub:
[Omar8345/CalculatorX](https://github.com/Omar8345/CalculatorX)

I want to calculate and view the answer on the GUI, I mostly did the most important part which I made a function which runs when the button is pressed and changes a variable it's name differs upon to the button name like `buttonClicked1` and `buttonClicked2` and when button is clicked, it's variable is set from `False` to `True`. And we can also add to return to the old value `False` after taking what we need from the variable, I mean the number, like `1` or `2` or `3` just examples. Code is on GitHub, help is much appreciated programmers... Thank you

Function for identifying which button pressed (Sample):

```py
def checkbutton1():
    global buttonClicked1
    buttonClicked1 = not buttonClicked1
    print('button 1 clicked')

buttonClicked1 = False  # set it false before clicking the button
```

Button 1 (Sample):

```py
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="1", width=10, height=10, command=checkbutton1)  # create button 1

button1.grid(row=3, column=1)  # arrange button 1 place

button1['font'] = font.Font(size=15)  # set button 1 font size
```

Full code is available on GitHub Repository, you can check [here](https://github.com/Omar8345/CalculatorX)

Comment: Please post relevant code inside the question itself

Comment: Okay, sure. No problem

Comment: Pardon me, but what is the question exactly?

Comment: Hey @Party-with-Programming I want to calculate and get the answer to view user, I made a function which runs when button is clicked, what it does it changes a variable to True, each button has it's variable, like `buttonClicked1` and now I made this function to help calculating, and my final result is be able to calculate and view to user the result.

Comment: So, is the GUI working or haven't you made it yet?

Comment: I made just buttons, like 1 2 3 and so on, but add and minus and equal and those not yet

Comment: The GUI is working

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be minimal, *complete* and representative. Information relevant to the question should be edited into the question, rather than left in [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). It's still entirely unclear what the issue is. Please read "[ask]" from the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really find the question but I suggest that you should not create a function for each button
what you should do is this

```
def checkButton(num):
   # whatever you want to do

button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text="1", width=10, height=10, command=lambda: checkButton(1)
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text="2", width=10, height=10, command=lambda: checkButton(2)

# And so on...
```

Also please edit your question to let us know what your real question is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh right, thanks for your suggestion, that actually helps, but that maybe brings me more to create the solution myself, but it might be little complicated to do it the solution , but I am sure it work.

Comment: I think I got the real solution now

Comment: Please tell me the question and the answer because I also tried to build a calculator but failed.